# CSS: active status

Tags: html, css, button

It's just a simple question. I made a button using `<a>` with background image. It should use different image when it is clicked. I use `:active` property in its css. But the thing is even after the button is not pressed (**release**), the `:active` class is still there. So it is still using the image for the status. 
How come? And how I should do it, when I only want to apply the class when the button is pressed?
Thank you. I hope I have explained it well enough.

Comment: Could it be that your `active` state is the same as your `visited`state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

works fine for me: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GLORIEN/kf6em/)

```
button {
    background-color: blue;
    border: none;
    color: #FFF;
}

button:hover {
    background-color: green
}

button:active {
    background-color: red
}
```

Can you provide a Demo to have a look in to it?

Comment: The OP is not using a button element. Although your solution is, of course, correct it does not fully address the issue.

Comment: It won't matter if it is a button or just a link. I updated the Fiddle to show one more way.

Answer (score 2):

catwoman, if you just want it while pressed active should work.  if you're looking for toggle, then you need what's below.

CSS doesn't have a selector that toggles, except for `:checked` on checked inputs.

You need Javascript:

`<a href="#" onclick="toggle_class('foo');"`

or to use jQuery Toggle: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

--

then again, if you are actually looking for button pressed, active should work.  paste your code here and we can check it out.  if you're doing something that can't be performed solely with css :active pseudoclass, look at the mousedown event: http://api.jquery.com/mousedown/

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to do it with pure css? Without jquery?

Comment: There's a checkmark hack with css.  Here's a good resource: http://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/